# spaces with isomorphic cohomology rings that are not homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Consider the spaces $X=\left(\mathbb{C} P^{\infty} \times S^{1}\right) /\left(\left\{x_{0}\right\} \times S^{1}\right)$ and $Y=\mathbb{C} P^{\infty} \times S^{3}$. I want to show that they have isomorphic cohomology rings but that they are not homotopy equivalent.

The cohomology ring of $Y$ is straightforward enough:
$$ H^*(Y;\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong H^*(\mathbb{C} P^\infty;\mathbb{Z}/2)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2} H^*(S^3;\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2[x]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/2}\mathbb{Z}/2[y]/(y^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2)$$
where $x$ is a generator of degree 2 and $y$ is a generator of degree 3.

<s>For $X$ we consider the fibration sequence
$$ *\to X\to\mathbb{C}P^\infty$$</s>

**Question 1** is this indeed a fibration sequence?

The corresponding Serre spectral sequence has $E_2$ page given by
$$ E_2^{ij}=\begin{cases}\mathbb{Z}/2,& j=0,i=2k\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
so all the differentials are trivial and $E_2=E_\infty$. So $H^*(X;\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong\mathbb{Z}/2[x]$, but I don't think this is isomorphic to the cohomology ring of $Y$, so I went wrong somewhere.

**Question 2** is the ring structure correct?

and finally, once I showed the two cohomology rings are isomorphic

**Question 3** how can I show $X$ and $Y$ are not homotopy equivalent?

Edit: Based on @KentaS's comment, the fibration sequence is indeed incorrect. @Thomas's reference suggests looking at the homotopy fiber of $p\colon Ci\to\mathbb{C} P^\infty$ - the extension of the projection $\pi\colon S^1\times\mathbb{C}P^\infty\to\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ to the mapping cone of the inclusion $i\colon S^1\to\mathbb{C} P^\infty\times S^1$ - but I can't figure out how to compute it. The author claims that the homotopy fiber is homotopy equivalent to $S^3$, citing [this](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN358147735_0039?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B299%5D%7D) reference, but I don't understand it.

Comment: If $*\to X\to\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ is a fibration sequence then $X$ and $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ would be homotopy equivalent (not just on the level of cohomology)

Comment: You perhaps can try to read  https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/2D4659A1F802DF98D4833F546148C999/S0004972700016154a.pdf/on_distinguishing_spaces_not_homotopyequivalent.pdf

Comment: @KentaS Right, that makes sense. So I guess $X\to\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ is not a fibration. Do you have a suggestion for a fibration sequence I can use here?

Comment: @Thomas That's a great reference! Thank you